# How to formally prove that $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}: n\geq N \implies e^{\sqrt{n}}>n^3$ without using calculus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to give a formal proof that $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}: n\geq N \implies e^{\sqrt{n}}>n^3$ without using calculus?

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: Any definition should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be shown by induction that for $m>30$ ... $2^m>m^6$. Now let $m=\sqrt{n}$ and use $e>2$.

Comment: How hard is the proof by induction?

Comment: @lhf Not very. Expand $(m+1)^6$ with the binomial theorem, and note that $m$ is large enough to give us $$6m^5 + 15m^4 + 20m^3+15m^2+6m+1<m^6$$(each of the five non-$1$ terms is less than $\frac15 m^6$) so $(m+1)^6<2m^6$.

Answer (score 6):

By the series definition of $e^x$, we have for any $n\geq 0$ that
$$
e^{\sqrt{n}} = 1 + \sqrt n + \frac{\sqrt n^2}{2!} + \frac{\sqrt n^3}{3!} + \cdots\\
> \frac{\sqrt n^7}{7!} = \frac{\sqrt n}{5040}\cdot n^3
$$
And we see immediately that for any $n\geq5040^2$ we have $e^{\sqrt n}>n^3$. Are there better bounds? Almost definitely. But that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
e^x = \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{k}}{k!}}
> \frac{x^{8}}{8!} 
$$
when $x>0$ and so
$$
e^{\sqrt{n}} > \frac{n^{4}}{8!} > n^3
$$
when $n>8! = 40320$.

Answer (score 0):

It is well-know that as of some $x$, $$e^x>ax,$$ (the exponential grows faster than any polynomial) and we can also prove by induction that if we find $x>1$ such that

$$e^x>ax$$ then $$e^{x+1}=e\,e^x>e\,ax>a(x+1).$$

Now with $$a=6,$$

we can choose $x>3$ and
$$e^x>6x,$$

$$e^{x'/6}>x'$$

$$e^{x'}>x'^6,$$

and

$$e^{\sqrt{x''}}>x''^3.$$

Comment: How does that prove $e^{\sqrt{n}}>n^3$?